# "illegal start of expression" ao compilar no CMD

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho o mini programa, que mostrarei a seguir. Ao compilar no prompt de comando, obtive um erro na linha 47 e que diz:

> illegal start of expression

Tenho no programa  uma lista de entradas do tamanho definido na `ListaArray`. Código:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NívelDePontos
{

   private static int identificar(Scanner kb, String mensagem, String mensagemErro) 
   {
        while (true) 
        {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            try 
            {
                return Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            {
                System.out.println(mensagemErro);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean lerSimNao(Scanner kb, String mensagem, String mensagemErro) 
    {
        while (true) 
       {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            String x = kb.nextLine();
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) return true;
            if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) return false;
            System.out.println(mensagemErro);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        {        
            int identidade = identificar(kb, "Introduza o número seu número de Telefone ou ID Thumba ", "Registamos um erro . Por favor, tente novamente.");
            System.out.println("Bem-vindo, utilizador" +" " + identidade + ".");

             int count, msg, nivel1;
             int[] ListaArray;   ListaArray = new int[100];

             while(msg <= nivel1)
             {
                 count = msg;
                 count++;
                 return <count>;            
             }

             System.out.println("Obrigado, até a próxima.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sempre que obter um erro, informe também onde é a linha do erro, você diz linha 47 mas onde é a linha 47?

Comment: `return <count>;` Esse trecho tem um erro de sintaxe, o certo é apenas `return count;`

Answer (score 1):

Como disse o @diegofm, a sintaxe é:

```
return count;
```

Seria mais simples

```
return msg + 1;
```

se considerar que você está igualando o valor de count na linha de cima. Talvez tenha um problema de lógica do jeito que o código foi construído.